# Is there a simple method to kill a process and all subprocess in linux system?

Tags: linux, process, pid, kill

When I want to kill a process using the pid in linux, its subprocess still existes. I hope to kill all process using one command.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting command `pkill -P PID pattern` .

Notice capital `P`.

See more documentation [here](https://manpage.me/?q=pkill).

Comment: Don't you mean `-P`? There doesn't appear to be a lower case `-p` option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out process groups:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group

Assuming you want to do this from a shell?
If you do a `kill` and make the top process negative it does a `killpg` under the covers and sends the signal to all the processes in the group.